# Modeling Privacy Settings in PHP/MySQL or PHP/NoSQL

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, nosql, relational-database

I'm building a private social network with Yii that will have "comments" all over the site - in Profiles, Events pages, Group Threads, etc.  When a user makes a post, they will be able to select the visibility of that content as:

- Anyone
- Registered Users Only
- Friends Only
- Custom (specific list of friends)

I'm trying to figure out how to model this for speed.  I've considered using MySQL for writing the setting into a binary "is_secure" field in the Comments table - if it is true, then go to a table with three columns: comment_id, user_id, and group_id.  Groups (group_id) would be for groups of users - Registered Users, Friends.  Custom would make one row for each user that is selected (user_id).

This table will get huge (perhaps several dozen rows for each comment), so I'm wondering if using NoSQL is worth considering here for retrieval only, or if there's a better way to model this.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question to database "flags". Search for related SO questions.

Instead of an `IF true/false` with the  `is_secure` field, just add 1-bit fields for `read_all` (anyone), `registered`, `friends`, `custom`. Add another table which holds the custom list would have `comment_id` (from the previous table) and `friend_id` (multiple rows). That way, in a single query with a `LEFT JOIN on custom_friends_list_for_comments` you can determine whether or not to show the page to a user. Optionally, custom could be a comma separated list (char field) but size limits might be an issue. Assuming 3-letter friend ids with a comma, each 255 char field can have 64 friends.